# Regex. Find in string any PHP GET variables

Tags: php, regex

Hello I'm trying to create a Regex that can find any GET variables from strings.
For example:

My function shoud return true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=test

Function shoud return false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

The pattern shoud find `?*anything*=`

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not yet sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want to find out, if a GET variable matches a regex? the value matches the regex? if the querystring (everything following the `?`) matches a regex? Please specify ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggests to take a look at [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function of php.

It breaks a url into components like `path` and `query`, so can check if a query exists in your uri or not, to get the path of uri etc.

In your example:

```
<?php
$uri = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=test';
parse_url($uri, $parts);
echo $parts['query']; #title=test
echo $parts['path']; #'question/ask

if (isset($parts['query']) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!